# PO file to XML with msgfmt: ITS rules not found

Tags: xml, gettext, msgfmt

I try to convert a PO file, which I created out of a XML file with an its rule over the command xgettext, back to the XML file with translation. But it seems msgfmt doesn't have an option to tell it where to find the its rule file (in xgettext there is an option --its).
My question is how do I tell msgfmt the its rule location?
or
How do I convert the PO file back to a translated XML file.

PS: I'm on windows and use mingw64

Thank you with kind regards
Mabenan

Comment: I encountered a similar error in Ubuntu, and installing the dependency `appstream` solved the issue. https://askubuntu.com/q/1273027/124466